# How can I know which part of regex is matched of Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have declare a `NSRegularExpression`. For example like `[0-9]{1,4}|abc|ABC` . And I input a `NSString: @"123"`. If I check the `NSTextCheckingResult`, it is not nil. So I know the string match the Regex. However, can I know more about which part is matched? For this scenario, I know Regex `[0-9]{1,4}` is matched. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: If first expression matches apply again with expression : [0-9]{1,4}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to use
*capture groups* `(...)`:

```
NSString *pattern = @"([0-9]{1,4})|(abc)|(ABC)";
```

If the string matches the first capture group in the pattern
then

```
[result rangeAtIndex:1]
```

will be the range of matching substring, while

```
[result rangeAtIndex:2]
[result rangeAtIndex:3]
```

have `range.location == NSNotFound`. Example:

```
NSString *pattern = @"([0-9]{1,4})|(abc)|(ABC)";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

NSString *str = @"123";
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange([result rangeAtIndex:1])); // {0, 3}
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange([result rangeAtIndex:2])); // {9223372036854775807, 0}
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange([result rangeAtIndex:3])); // {9223372036854775807, 0}
```

Comment: Awesome.. Your answer is correct! I wonder to know what is `[result rangeAtIndex:0]` ?

Comment: `rangeAtIndex:0` has the same value as `range`: the range that matches the entire pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> and type `NSTextCheckingResult` or <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on the symbol to get the class definition.

There are properties `range`, `resultType`, `numberOfRanges` and many more.

Or call `rangeOfFirstMatchInString:options:range` on the `NSRegularExpression` instance to get the range directly.